# Create table in specific tablespace with SQLalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I can create new table in tablespace using raw query:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_DDS, encoding="utf-8")
connection = engine.connect()
conn = engine.raw_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = """
        CREATE TABLE {schema}.{table_name}
        (
            ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
            STATUS NVARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
            DESCR NVARCHAR2(256) DEFAULT NULL
        )
        TABLESPACE SOME_TABLESPACE
        """.format(table_name = table_name, schema = SCHEMA)
    cur.execute(sql)
```

Created table is accesseble for all users with privileges. But how to do same thing without *raw_connection*? With this approach:

```
metadata = MetaData(engine)
table = Table('Example',metadata,
              Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column('status',String))
metadata.create_all()
```

How to specify tablespase for new table?

Such code works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'status', 'descr']) # pandas data frame
df.to_sql(con=connection, name=tbl, schema=SCHEMA, index=False, dtype=data_types, if_exists='replace')
```

but when tring to insert any data i got:

```
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

Comment: You could maybe adjust the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965630/how-to-create-a-partitioned-oracle-table-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: @IljaEverilä, I saw this answer before question creation. I don't undestand how to put tablespase to table info. And can't find it in documentation. Tnks!

Comment: Basically you'd have to extend compiling `CreateTable` to support the additional attributes.

Comment: Perhaps this is a configuration problem, and the database user is not setup with a good default tablespace.  Can you work around this problem with a statement like `alter user some_user default tablespace some_tablespace`?

Comment: @JonHeller, thanks for your solution. I don't have such priveleges, but I'll try to ask DB administrator to configure default tablespace. But such approach not aplicable when user have to work in multiply tablespaces.